# Docker swarm multiple IPs for/in container

Tags: linux, networking, docker-swarm

I started to play around with docker swarm (3 nodes).

Recently i discovered that when a container is started (simple web server) with `docker run --net=custom_overlay` and not deployed as a service, the container has 2 network interfaces attached:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6389: eth0@if6390: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:0a:00:02:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.16/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6391: eth1@if6392: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.7/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The problem im facing is, that even when the HTTP server listens on `0.0.0.0`, i can reach it only with the `172.18.0.7` IP from the same node.

Example: `curl http://172.18.0.7` works, this not: `curl http://10.0.2.16`.

Can some one pleas explain why this happens?
I guess the `10.0.2.16` is the custom (ingress?) overlay network, and the `172.18.0.7` the default docker deamon one?

But why answer the server only on one IP?